# Touchscreen doesn't work on Ubuntu 15.10 (Toshiba Satellite Radius P55W-B)

Tags: usb, 15.10, touchscreen, usbhid

I very recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 to dualboot alongside windows 10 and the touchscreen on my laptop seemed to work for a while and then it stopped working at some unknown time.  From the research I've done, there seem to be a range of utilities that help in trouble shooting input device issues. Here are a few:

x-input results in the following output.  Before the screen stopped working I believe that there was a third entry in the "Virtual core pointer" section of the output:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Power Button                               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Video Bus                                  id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Power Button                               id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD                    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Toshiba input device                       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:7046 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 107: ID 04f3:0381 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This is what's in /proc/bus/input/devices

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000e Version=0000
N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e420 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=661800011000003

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Toshiba input device"
P: Phys=toshiba_acpi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=40000 0 1c00000000 0 0 1401b00000000 0 2000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04ca Product=7046 Version=0003
N: Name="TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-6/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input18
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input23
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input24
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input25
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

Thanks, this has been driving me crazy.